# MongooseError [MissingSchemaError]: Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I need a little help, I've a category schema, which looks like below,

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let schema = mongoose.Schema;
const _ = require("lodash");

let category = new schema(
  {
    // Primary Fields
    categoryName: { type: String, unique: true },
    isArchived: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    categoryImage: { type: String },
    categorySlug: { type: String, unique: true },
    createdBy:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users",
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

let Category = mongoose.model("Categories", category);
module.exports = {
    Category,
};
```

and I'm using this reference into another schema, which looks like below,

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { ObjectID } = require("mongodb");

let coupons = new schema({
    city: {type:String},
    categoryId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "categories",
    },
    offerCode: {type:String,unique:true},
    couponName: {type:String,unique:true},
    validFrom: {type:Date},
    validTill: {type:Date},
    visibility: { type:Boolean,default:false},
    issuedFor: {type:String,enum:['BIKE','AUTO','DELIVERY','CHARGING']},
    applicability: {type:String,enum:['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','0']},
    bankType: {type:String},
    isArchived: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users",
    },
},
{
    timestamps: true,
});
    coupons.index( { "offerCode": 1,"couponName": 1,"validFrom": 1, "validTill":1, "categoryId":1 }, { unique: true } );
    let Coupons = mongoose.model("Coupons", coupons);
    module.exports = {
         Coupons
    };
```

everything looks pretty much good, I can use reference of other schema but the category schema is throwing `MongooseError` whenever I'm trying to populate this from my code.

The code looks like below,

```
return await Coupons.find(query)
        .populate('categoryId')
        .skip(parseInt(skip)).select(select).limit(parseInt(limit)).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
```

can anyone please tell me what is wrong that leads me towards `MongooseError [MissingSchemaError]: Schema hasn't been registered for model "categories".`

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste the code instead of upload screenshots cause will be better to read this post

Comment: @Kafarson done. can you please help. Thanks

Comment: sorry if i wrong (cause i not a expert) but did you try change ref to PascalCase ?,    `categoryId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Categories",
    },` Because your call other shema like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format would be:

```js
categoryId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
    },
```

You need to change the name of your model too:

```js
let Category = mongoose.model("Category", category);
```

Mongoose will look for the pularized, lowercase collection of the model name, so mongoose assumes `Category` -> `categories`.

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the tanks collection in the database.

Then when you do the populate you can always explicitly specify the `path` and `model` like so

```js
return await Coupons.find(query)
        .populate({path: 'categoryId', model: Category})
        .skip(parseInt(skip)).select(select).limit(parseInt(limit)).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
```

See [Compiling your first model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling) and [Saving refs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs) for full explanation.

Comment: Damn, it worked, Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

from this code `mongoose.model("Categories", category);`, you are defining this model with the name of `Categories`. so you will have to use the same name wherever you want to reference it.
this below code should work for you.

```
categoryId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Categories", // note: C is capitalized. 
    },
```